# Expected value (and variance) of a Dirichlet Process

Tags: nonparametric, density-estimation, dirichlet-process

Suppose I have a measure $G$ that follows a Dirichlet Process,

$$G \sim DP(H_0,\alpha)$$

where $H_0$ is some base measure. Is there a closed form solution for the expected value of $G$?

Comment: It simply is $H_0$.

Comment: Awesome, and what about the variance? That should involve alpha right?

Comment: Don't forget $G$ is a *measure*; how are you defining the variance of a measure?

Comment: Well I guess if we can define E[G] then we should be able to define E[G^2]?